# How can I use PHP date to display certain elements?

Tags: php, date, validation

I'm trying to create a PHP loop that has a start and end date, but will also compare the current date to divs which can only be triggered on a certain date. I have click events per div to add class's etc.

The idea of this is for a calendar so I need the dates to start at 1st of December and finish on the 24th, with each div having its own validation so it **can't be opened before** its set date and if the current date has passed its set date, add a different class.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php

$current = date('d-m-y');
$start = '01-12-19';
$end = '24-12-19';
$datecount = 1; 
$countstart = "01-12-19"; 

if ($start <= $curent && $end >= $current) {

switch ($datecount) {
    case 1:
        break;
    case 2:
        date(d-m-y, strtotime($countstart. ' + 1 day'));
        $datecount ++;
        echo "
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
        $('#door1').removeClaas('blocked');
        </script>
        ";
        break;
    case 3:
        date(d-m-y, strtotime($countstart. ' + 2 day'));
        $datecount ++;
        break;   
    case 4:
        date(d-m-y, strtotime($countstart. ' + 3 day'));
        $datecount ++;
        break;
    case 5:
        date(d-m-y, strtotime($countstart. ' + 4 day'));
        $datecount ++;
        break;          
}

}


?>
```

Am I on the right track? Am I better off trying this in JS?

Answer (score 1):

I would go about it differently:

Create an array with all of the days, like so:

```
$decemberDays = array();
$decemberDays[1]["message"] = "Yeah! December first!";
$decemberDays[2]["message"] = "23 more days to Xmas!";
...
$decemberDays[24]["message"] = "Xmas eve!";
```

Then I would simply loop through the array until the current date:

```
$month = date('n'); // "n" is the month without leading zeros
if ($month === 12){
   $day = date('j'); //"j" is the day without leading zeros
   for ($i = 1; $i<=$day; $i++){
       echo "<div>Dec $i: $decemberDays[$i]['message']</div>";
   }
}
```

Instead of adding divs and removing them afterwards, you can simply figure out what divs are needed and create only those.

(I haven't tested the code, it's just meant to demo the idea).

Answer (score 0):

You can render your markup according the desired conditions.
With the help of [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), [DateInterval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) and [DatePeriod](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) classes you can generate the dates for the advent calendar.
Then using [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [closure](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) you can setup the necessary markup:

```
$start = new DateTime('2019-12-01');
$end = new DateTime('2019-12-24');
$end = $end->modify('+1 day');
$today = new DateTime('2019-12-04');

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$range = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

$markup = array_map(function($date) use ($today) {
    return sprintf('<div%s>%s</div>', ($date->format('Y-m-d') <= $today->format('Y-m-d')) ? '' : ' class="blocked"', $date->format('Y-m-d'));
}, iterator_to_array($range));

print_r($markup);
```

*Note*: You can use `new DateTime('TODAY');` for today's date.

Result is an array with the desired markup, you only need to `implode` it:

```
[0] => <div>2019-12-01</div>
[1] => <div>2019-12-02</div>
[2] => <div>2019-12-03</div>
[3] => <div>2019-12-04</div>
[4] => <div class="blocked">2019-12-05</div>
[5] => <div class="blocked">2019-12-06</div>
[6] => <div class="blocked">2019-12-07</div>
[7] => <div class="blocked">2019-12-08</div>
[8] => <div class="blocked">2019-12-09</div>
[9] => <div class="blocked">2019-12-10</div>
[10] => <div class="blocked">2019-12-11</div>
[11] => <div class="blocked">2019-12-12</div>
[12] => <div class="blocked">2019-12-13</div>
[13] => <div class="blocked">2019-12-14</div>
[14] => <div class="blocked">2019-12-15</div>
[15] => <div class="blocked">2019-12-16</div>
[16] => <div class="blocked">2019-12-17</div>
[17] => <div class="blocked">2019-12-18</div>
[18] => <div class="blocked">2019-12-19</div>
[19] => <div class="blocked">2019-12-20</div>
[20] => <div class="blocked">2019-12-21</div>
[21] => <div class="blocked">2019-12-22</div>
[22] => <div class="blocked">2019-12-23</div>
[23] => <div class="blocked">2019-12-24</div>
```